Why is a cavity with discrete modes necessary in the derivation of Planck's law?
In my readings, I have come across the concept that a finite cavity allows for the quantization of electromagnetic modes, leading to discrete energy levels. However, it's not clear to me why this step is essential. Wouldn't it be possible to derive the same law without assuming a cavity, perhaps by considering the continuum of modes in an open space? Additionally, if not all frequencies are allowed in a finite cavity, how does the derived radiation distribution end up being continuous? This seems counterintuitive to me, as I would expect a discrete set of modes to yield a discrete spectrum rather than a continuous one.
I'd appreciate it if someone could clarify the physical and mathematical necessity of this assumption in the context of Planck's law derivation :D

It's mathematically convenient to solve the discrete problem and then get the continuous result as a limit.

@JohnDoty But is the cavity even a black body radiator if the waves inside aren’t continuous? I don’t really get why considering finite modes first would make it easier. When deriving e.g maxwell-Boltzmann law you wouldn’t consider the density of states made of discrete points either.
